# reduce the preposition "at" or not?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I heard the question: "Are you mad at me?" in a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7GfP7kX9gY pronounced in two different ways:

'ɑr yu 'mæd **æ**t mi?

and

'ɑr yu 'mæd **ə**t mi?

Sometimes the preposition "at" is pronounced in the strong (æt) form even if it's not stressed. In a normal context like the youtube video above, does it matter if I use the strong form (æt) or the weak form (ət)?

When I pronounce the question above I put a bit of stress on "are" and "mad". Am I correct? I think that we also have a rising intonation at the end of the question, because it's a YES/NO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context you give here, there is no difference whatsoever. Whether you reduce the vowel or not is entirely a matter of what you feel like doing right then and there.

It’s possible that dialect also plays a part (I have a vague hunch that many speakers of Southern US dialects would be less likely to reduce the vowel than other speakers), but both versions can and do exist in all dialects of English.

You’re correct about the rising intonation and the primary stress on *mad*. You can put a weak, secondary stress on *are* as well, or you can leave it entirely unstressed with no real difference in meaning. You can also, colloquially, leave out the vowel in *are* or the whole word entirely with no discernible difference in meaning; respectively:

> ’r you mad at me?
>   You mad at me?

If you put more (i.e., primary) stress on *are*, then you’re emphasising:

> *Are* you mad at me? A moment ago you said you weren’t!

Answer (score 0):

I watched the video.  I think your observations are entirely correct.  As other matters of interest, the "d" of "mad" is often a flap and the "t" of "at" is often a glottal stop.